# Миграция домена с Windows Server 2003 на Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server, windows-server-2008-r2

Миграцию провожу на основе [данной](http://www.techdays.ru/videos/1491.html) инструкции от специалиста Microsoft. Сделав всё по инструкции, начинаю самый важный момент - миграцию леса. Запускаю `DCPROMO`, указываю "Существующий лес => добавить контроллер домена в существующий лес", указываю пользователя, затем в течении нескольких минут происходит проверка конфигурации DNS. В качестве дополнительных параметров для контроллера выбираю: - DNS-сервер - Глобальный каталог Дохожу до "Сводка", жму далее и получаю ошибку:Указанный домен не существует или к нему невозможно подключится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась следующим:
Как оказалось. Когда-то сеть между мои зданием и ещё одним филиалом, видимо была объединена в один единый КД. Позже, по каким-то причинам от этой идеи отказались и сеть в моём здании оказалась самостоятельной. В итоге, длительное и томительное чтение логов действительно указало на этот факт. Периодически КД в моём здании пытался реплицировать на какой-то левый домен. Конечно же, об этом меня не предупредили.

Answer (score 0):

У меня решилось выполнением всего из под пользователя "Администратор".

Comment: К сожалению, это не решило проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Больше всего что не указали коректный днс сервер в настройках сети.Так как контролер новый - при дкпромо измените днс сервер на днс сервер существуещего контролера